# calling a __host__ function from a __host__ __device__ functon is not allowed

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I am trying to use thrust with Opencv classes. The final code will be more complicated including using device memory but this simple example does not build successfully.

```
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

//#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/remove.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp>

#include <iostream>

struct is_zero
{
  __host__  __device__ 
  bool operator()(const cv::KeyPoint x)
  {
    return x.response  == 0.0;
  }
};


int main(void){

cv::KeyPoint h_data[5]; 


h_data[0]=  cv::KeyPoint(cv::Point2f(3,4),0.3);
h_data[1]=  cv::KeyPoint(cv::Point2f(2,6),0.3);
h_data[2]=  cv::KeyPoint(cv::Point2f(1,1),0.3);
h_data[3]=  cv::KeyPoint(cv::Point2f(2,8),0.3);
h_data[4]=  cv::KeyPoint(cv::Point2f(2,6),0.3);


h_data[0].response=0.3;
h_data[1].response=0.0;
h_data[2].response=0.5;
h_data[3].response=0.0;
h_data[4].response=0.6;


cv::KeyPoint *new_data_end = thrust::remove_if(h_data, h_data + 5, is_zero());  //this does not work

}
```

As you can see I am not even passing the host memory variable to device memory or anything.

When I try to build I got

```
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/system/cuda/detail/par.h(141): warning: calling a __host__ function("cv::Point_<float> ::Point_") from a __host__ __device__ function("cv::KeyPoint::KeyPoint") is not allowed

/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/system/cuda/detail/par.h(141): warning: calling a __host__ function("cv::Point_<float> ::Point_") from a __host__ __device__ function("cv::KeyPoint::KeyPoint [subobject]") is not allowed

/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/system/cuda/detail/par.h(141): warning: calling a __host__ function("cv::Point_<float> ::operator =") from a __host__ __device__ function("cv::KeyPoint::operator =") is not allowed
```

How can I use thrust remove_if with opencv classes?

(My plan is to use remove_if with an array of `cv::KeyPoint` in the future)

Comment: Note that is only a warning, and for this case in host code it can be ignored. But for the device usage you (no doubt) eventually have in mind, you can't and the warnings will become errors . For this to work, you require copy construction of a host side object in device code. That isn't allowed. Thrust algorithms are, in general, only designed to work with POD types and objects which are trivially constructible.

Comment: That is very interesting. Do you reckon there is a way to do stream compaction to arrays in which the elements are objects?

Comment: Yes, and I said as much in my first comment. But not *this particular* class for the reasons I already outlined. If the class isn't trivially constructible or does not have a device constructor, then it won't work. This appears to be such a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, *for the code you have shown*, you are getting a *warning* and this warning can be safely ignored.

For usage in CUDA device code:

For a C++ class to be usable in CUDA device code, any relevant member functions that will be used explicitly or implicitly in CUDA device code, [must be marked](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-function-specifier) with the `__device__` decorator.  (There are a few exceptions e.g. for defaulted constructors which don't apply here.)

The OpenCV class you are attempting to use ([`cv::KeyPoint`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/d29/classcv_1_1KeyPoint.html)), doesn't meet these requirements for use in device code.  It won't be usable as-is.

There may be a few options:

1. Recast your work using `cv::KeyPoint` to use some class that provides similar functionality, that you write yourself, in such a way as to be properly designed and decorated.
2. Perhaps see if OpenCV built with CUDA has an alternate version here (properly designed/decorated) (my guess would be it probably doesn't)
3. Rewrite OpenCV itself, taking into account all necessary design changes to allow the `cv::KeyPoint` class to be usable in device code.
4. As a variant of suggestion 1, copy the relevant data `.response` to a separate set of classes or just a bare array, and do your selection work based on that.  The selection work done there can be used to "filter" the original array.